# PHP Facebook API - Email return null

Tags: php, facebook, api

I have code like this:

```
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://MyAwesomeWebsite.com/' );

    try {
        $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
    } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
        echo print_r($ex);
    } catch( Exception $ex ) {
        echo print_r($ex);
    }
    if ( isset( $session ) ) {
        $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me?locale=en_US&fields=name,email' );
        $response = $request->execute();
        $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

        $fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');              // To Get Facebook ID
        $fbfullname = $graphObject->getProperty('name'); // To Get Facebook full name
        $femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email');    // To Get Facebook email ID
    }
```

But every time $femail is null. Why? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: User may not granted your application to acces their mail address ? Did you try it yourself ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you log in the user, you have to pass along the [email permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-email) in the `scope` parameter.

So when you call your helper, also initialise a `$permissions` array:

```
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://MyAwesomeWebsite.com/' );
$permissions = ['email', 'public_profile'];
```

There should be `$helper->getLoginUrl` call in somewhere in your code. In that call you should pass the `$permissions` variable as the second parameter:

```
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($placeYourCallbackURLHere, $permissions);
```

That asks the user explicitly for a permission to get the user's email. Note that the email can also be empty, if the user has:

1. Registered to Facebook via phone number (does not have email address in Faceebook)
2. Selected that they do not want to provide the email address at the login prompt.

Comment: Thanks but I'm using above raw code to register user so this solution is not for me :/

Comment: @FilipNowacki What are you using for user login with Facebook? I can modify the answer to match your code. The point is, that you're missing a `scope="email"` parameter somewhere in your code. Can you include the login code in your question?

Comment: I'm using Facebook api to login and register user in my website.
My login code is very simple. It's only <a href...> with address mywebsite.com/register_fb, there is only above code from main question so it's hard to insert scope="email" I think.

Comment: @FilipNowacki edited the answer to match your current code, missed that `FacebookRedirectLoginHelper` before.